# save decorator with morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, decorator, morphia

for a multiplayer game project that I'm building I have a little database based on **morphia MongoDB**.

when all the users of a game room is logged out, I want to save the Game object to the DB to save the server's RAM,
but my Game object designed as **decorator** (the classic design pattern with no changes)

so my object's ID is an Object that its ID is also an Object and the hierarchy length is dynamic....

is there any way to declare the ID to be the ID's ID?

for example in hierarchy of length 3 i use for read

```
Query<IGame> query = datastore.createQuery(IGame.class).filter("_id._id._id = ", "28");
```

and in hierarchy of length 4 i use

```
Query<IGame> query = datastore.createQuery(IGame.class).filter("_id._id._id._id = ", "28");
```

but i need a combination with a dynamic length of _id._id
or another way to store this hierarchy in morphia.